# How to download free APP for testing, with 'Pending Developer Release' Status

Tags: ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

i have Free iPad APP on iTunes, and now it showing status as 'Pending Developer Release'. as i had selected Manual release.

i would like to test App on my iPad before i Release for my Clients. as past 2-3 Release went wrong as it was automatically release to App store once approved.

i generated 1 promo code after reading some content on NET. but i am not able to understand how i can delete my new version .

is it possible to download APP when status is 'Pending Developer Release'.

Comment: From the app store no this version. From the test flight yes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found two solutions to my problem:

1. Test Flight , adding internal tester from developer team having admin/Technical role.
2. Generate promo codes for App and redeem on iPad.